# MessagePrompt crashing at first launch of application

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a problem that I am using coding4fun dll in my WP7 application for showing the popup messages.
I am using:

1. Micrsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit
2. Coding4fun.Phone.Controls

At first launch of deployment on device its crashing saying that value cannot be null(parameter name element) while on emulator its running fine. I have tried the latest version of this dll but the result was same.

While adding Micrsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit of latest version 1.4.8 is giving warning that adding a silverlight library may result in unexpected consequences.

while I tried other version of this dll still no success.

I am getting exception in stacktrace

1. Clarity.Phone.Extensions.DialogService.InitializePopUp
2. Clarity.Phone.Extensions.DilaogService.Show

Basically i am using that popup inside constuctor of mainpage.xaml(first page) after InitializeComponent() and it is throwing null reference type at first launch while deploying but app is getting installed. again if i run application on device then it is appearing correctly. 
My code is:

```
notificationPrompt = new MessagePrompt();
notificationPrompt.Title = "Notification"
notificationPrompt.Body = "";
notificationPrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Clear();
Button btnDisclaimer = new Button() { Content = "Yes" };
btnDisclaimerContinue.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnNotificationPromptYes_Click);
Button btnDisclaimerCancel = new Button() { Content = "No" };
btnDisclaimerCancel.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnNotificationPromptNo_Click);
notificationPrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Add(btnDisclaimerContinue);
notificationPrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Add(btnDisclaimerCancel);
notificationPrompt.Show();
```

Comment: I tried this code with the latest coding4fun library and it works fine, maybe you can provide more code or details. Referring to the warning, could it be that you try to include the silverlight toolkit and not the windows phone toolkit? Both could be found on http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: this is working fine on emulator but throwing null reference exception in device and also adding latest version of dll that is version 1.4.8 it was giving warning while adding microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit(silverlight warning).

Comment: basically i am using that popup inside constuctor of mainpage.xaml(first page) after InitializeComponent() and it is throwing null reference type at first launch while deploying but app is getting installed. again if i run application on device then it is appearing correctly.

Comment: well, did you try to move the prompt.Show() into the loaded event?

Comment: Thanks Jan K thanks alot for reminding me the Loaded event. I was using Loaded in other pages but since in this first page there was no data to load so I was directly calling method in constructor. I moved my whole method from constructor to loaded event and it worked perfectly. I think the problem was that root visual for popup to appear was not created before the popup appears hence throwing null reference exception. Once againg thanks alot man!!

Comment: But still one thing I didn't get that why it was crashing at deployment only? and also after crashing it was getting installed correctly and if then i start it from device those pop ups were appearing correctly without any crash. It should crash after installation also if root visual is necessary for child to appear And also in emulator it was working fine sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's the better to move all this code outside the constructor, and put it inside the Loaded event (occurs when a FrameworkElement has been constructed and added to the object tree: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596558(vs.95)) of the PhoneApplicationPage class, or just override the OnNavigatedTo method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    // What you want here...
    ...
}
```

Often when you have exceptions in the constructor of a PhoneApplicationPage, they will not show, making the debug more difficult and annoying...

Comment: The OP states that he *is* receiving an exception; while it's standard (and recommended) practice to not put any logic-based code in a constructor, your answer feels too much like a comment and doesn't help with the question.